# Disk not visible in My computer, still accessible

Tags: hard-drive, disk-management

I have 6 domain connected computers, they all have an extra 4 TB disk in them.
The disks have been assigned to Q: on all computers. (There is no network drive assigned to Q:)

On 4 of these computer the drive is not visible in my computer.
I am however able to access the drive by writing Q: in the address bar.
On the other 2 computer the Q: drive is visible.

Everything looks OK to me in disk management and I have unassigned the disk from Q: and set the drive to Q: again but the issue remains.

The disks are synced with Dropbox and I really want to avoid wiping the disks since it takes forever to sync 4 TB with Dropbox.

Suggestions on how to make the drives visible are very appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to hide (or unhide) drives in Explorer using Group Policy or Registry. If such a thing had happened on all computers, I'd have suggested you to inspect your domain policies to see if a group policy is enforced on them, but seeing as you have this problem only on 4 computers I suggest you do the following on all four:

1. Open Registry Editor by pressing Windows+R key combination, typing `regedit` and pressing Enter.
2. Using the left pane, go to the following key: `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer` (First open HKEY_CURRENT_USER, then Software, then Microsoft, etc.)
3. In the right pane, look for a parameter called "NoDrives". If you see it, delete it.
   [image]
4. Restart Windows

Here is some further reading:

- "[Hide physical drives in Windows Explorer](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/555438)". Support. Microsoft.
- "[Hide Drives from Your Computer in Windows 7 or Vista](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/hide-drives-from-your-computer-in-windows-vista/)". How-To Geek.

Comment: Link-only answers are considered a no-no due to possible future link-rot.  Please add pertinent information directly to your answers, and cite the sources as required.

Comment: Please cite and quote all relevant information from your links.  Answers by themselfs should answer a question.  Answers that contain just links are subject to be removed by the community.

Comment: The disk is not visible when showing hidden items.
I will check Regedit, but can it be hidden there without someone manually adding it there?

Comment: Submit a screenshot of Disk Mangement from one of the PCs where the drive is not shown in explorer.  In addition to that submit a screenshot of the `This PC/Computer/Ect.` in the current view configuration but in `Details` mode.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like they may be hidden. Change the setting in Windows Explorer / File Explorer to show hidden items. For example, on Windows 10:

[image]

Once you can view the disks unhide them (Right click => Properties => General => Attributes => Hidden)